# Pass generated ID to next page using POST method

Tags: php, mysql

In my system when users add a reservation to the database, a transaction ID will be automatically generated:

```
$insertID = mysql_insert_id() ;
$transactionID = "RESV2014CAI00". $insertID ;
$insertGoTo = "action.php?trans=" . $transact;
```

But it is very dangerous to pass the `$transactionID` via address bar. (GET Method) So I need to send transaction to `action.php` via the POST method.

How can I pass this data using the POST method?

Comment: POST is only safer than GET for the most naive.

Comment: Is it possible to send transaction id via url?

Comment: It's **possible** to use both GET and POST. Whether it's safe or not is a different matter. If transaction id is very sensitive information, HTTPS should be considered.

Comment: You need to use `CURL` or put that value in `Session`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to hash the id as shown below.

```
$salt = 'your secret key here';
$hash = sha1(md5($transactionID.$salt));
```

Now you can pass the hash along with the transaction id on the next page and check it match. If it matches then the id wasn't changed. If not then the id was changed. Something like.

```
$salt = 'your secret key here';
$hash = sha1(md5($_GET['transectionId'].$salt));

if($hash == $_GET['hash']){
  //do something
} else {
   //Error, id changed
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why the md5 hash as well as the sha1?

Comment: @RyanVincent Just to make it hard to decypher.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the `$transactionID` from one page to another in your website you can also use `$_SESSION`.

Information in the basic usage can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: Thank You Eric
Can you give an example, how can I add transaction ID to session ?

Comment: Using session can get very annoying if you're the sort of person that uses multiple tabs. You'll get bleed from one tab to another if you do this. Try not to.

Comment: @Margo take a look at this documentation you will get it how to set ID in session [http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php]